# Passing arguments to Python function as a data structure

Tags: python, function, arguments

I am using a 3rd party library function which has a large number of positional and named arguments. The function is called from numerous points in my code with identical arguments/values.

For ease of maintenance I don't want to hard-code the dozens of identical arguments multiple times throughout my code. I was hoping there was a way of storing them once in a data structure so I just need to pass the data structure. Along the lines of the following:

Assume the signature of the function I'm calling looks like:

```
def lib_function(arg1, arg2, arg3=None, arg4=None):
```

Assume that throughout my code I want to call it with values of

- `a` for arg1,
- `b` for arg2
- `d` for arg4
- (and I'm not using arg3).

I've tried defining a data structure as follows:

```
arguments = ('a', 'b', {'arg4':'d'})
```

and using it like this:

```
res = lib_function(arguments)
```

but this is obviously not correct - the tuple and dict are not unpacked during the call but are handled as a single first argument.

Is there a way of doing this in Python?

The obvious alternative is to proxy lib_function in my code, with the arguments hard-coded in the proxy which is then called with no arguments. Something like:

```
def proxy_lib_function():
    return lib_function('a', 'b', arg4='d')

res = proxy_lib_function()
```

However I wanted to check there isn't a more Pythonic way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate positional and named arguments and use [asterisk unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters):

```
def lib_function(arg1, arg2, arg3=None, arg4=None):
    print(locals())


args = ("a", "b")
kwargs = {"arg4": "d"}
res = lib_function(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Please take your time and answer with text and explantion at first time, a code-only answer does not really help

Comment: Yes that does the job.  Thanks.

Comment: @azro, if the guy says it does the job, then I guess it's enough :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function is:

```
 def lib_function(arg1, arg2, arg3=None, arg4=None):
```

Define another function:

```
 def yourFunction(x):
    return lib_function(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3])
```

The "data structure" would be:

```
data = [yourData1, yourData2, yourData3, yourData4]
```

Then you can call your new function with this:

```
yourFunction(data)
```